# Read matrix from .txt file

Tags: c, matrix

This is something kinda hard for me, as the tutorials I found are not really useful, and the answers I found here were quite confusing... I have this .txt file:

```
1  5  4  7  8  9  6  5  4  7  8  9
4  8  7  5  2  6  9  8  5  4  4  7
3  3  2  5  9  9  7  4  5  6  9  8
1  7  3  6  5  4  7  8  5  1  4  2
9  5  1  2  3  5  7  8  4  6  5  5
4  5  9  6  8  2  3  4  8  1  6  3
8  4  5  3  2  0  1  2  6  9  8  7
0  2  3  5  4  8  9  5  1  5  6  5
1  2  0  4  5  9  3  5  7  1  9  4
4  8  9  5  6  7  8  4  9  1  5  2
6  3  5  9  8  4  2  3  5  6  7  8
3  0  2  9  4  0  5  8  9  7  3  1
```

And I need to convert it into a

```
int matr[12][12];
```

How do I structure my code in order to put all those numbers into a matrix?
I know I'm supposed to use fscanf and pointers, but I keep getting errors like

> cannot convert 'const char*' to 'FILE* {aka _iobuf*}' for argument '1' to 'int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)'

So please, just give me some light here.

Comment: I suggest you provide some source code to show what you are doing and where the error is coming from.

Comment: Not "convert" but "create the array and fill it with values you read from file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what (little) you have provided, I think your problem is that `fscanf()` expects a `FILE *` as its first argument, but you are providing the name of the file as a `const char *`.

You can get a `FILE *` by using `fopen()`.

```
FILE * fileptr = fopen("<name of file in double quotes>", "r"); // open file for reading
if (fileptr == NULL) /* do some error handling stuff */;
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < 12; ++j)
        fscanf(fileptr, "%d", &matr[i][j]);
// Some important matrix stuff...
fclose(fileptr); // close your file when done
```